# Where is the infinite loop occurring?

Tags: c++

This problem comes from leetcode:

Given an array of integers nums sorted in ascending order, find the starting and ending position of a given target value.

Your algorithm's runtime complexity must be in the order of O(log n).

If the target is not found in the array, return [-1, -1].

Example 1:

Input: nums = [5,7,7,8,8,10], target = 8
Output: [3,4]

Here is my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<int> searchRange(vector<int>& nums, int target)
{
    int left = 0;
    int right = (int)nums.size() - 1;
    std::vector<int> result;
    while(left <= right)
    {
        auto mid = (int)(left + right) / 2;
        if(nums[mid] < target)
            left = mid + 1;
        else
            right = mid;
    }

    int next_left = left;
    int next_right = (int) nums.size() - 1;
    while(next_left < next_right)
    {
        auto mid = (int)(left + right + 1) / 2;
        if(nums[mid] > target)
            next_right = mid - 1;
        else
            next_left = mid;
    }

    result = {next_left, next_right};

    return result;


}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums = {1,2,2,2,2,4};
    int target = 2;

    auto result = searchRange(nums, target);
    for(auto it: result)
        std::cout << it << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting a Time Limit Exceeded. I don't know how to fix it any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second loop, this line

```
auto mid = (int)(left + right + 1) / 2;
```

should probably be

```
auto mid = (int)(next_left + next_right + 1) / 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion for tracking down the logic error.

Add couple of lines in the `while` loops to see how the indices are changing.

```
while(left <= right)
{
    auto mid = (int)(left + right) / 2;
    if(nums[mid] < target)
        left = mid + 1;
    else
        right = mid;

    // Debugging output.
    std::cout << "left: " << left
              << ", mid: " << mid
              << ", right: " << right << std::endl;
}
```

and

```
while(next_left < next_right)
{
    // Incorrect.
    // auto mid = (int)(left + right + 1) / 2;

    auto mid = (int)(next_left + next_right + 1) / 2;
    if(nums[mid] > target)
        next_right = mid - 1;
    else
        next_left = mid;

    // Debugging output.
    std::cout << "next_left: " << next_left
              << ", mid: " << mid
              << ", next_right: " << next_right << std::endl;
}
```

That should lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Doesn't directly answer the question (that is, doesn't point out and explain the error), but still quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

To Find Left Index

```
    auto mid = (int)(left + right) / 2;
```

To Find Right Index

```
    auto mid = (int)(next_left + next_right + 1) / 2;
```

I think you should use

```
result = {left, next_right};
```

to return correct result it working with {-1,-1}